# 'Cannot instantiate class' error in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I get the following error when I run my code:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class com.SF.TestCases.Administrator_Test_Case
at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:40)
at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:382)
at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:295)
at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:118)
at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:183)
at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:128)
at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:416)
at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:242)
at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:212)
at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:166)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:143)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:272)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:587)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:161)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:114)
at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1290)
at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1277)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1131)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:112)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:212)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:102)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:71)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
at com.SF.Pages.SFQA_Administrator.<init>(SFQA_Administrator.java:17)
at com.SF.TestCases.Administrator_Test_Case.<init>(Administrator_Test_Case.java:16)
... 26 more
```

Below is the code:

```
package com.SF.Pages;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class SFQA_Administrator {

WebDriver driver1;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver1,20);
By SysopUserName = By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_Login1_UserName");
By SysopPassword = By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_Login1_Password");
By AdminLoginButton = By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_Login1_ButtonSubmit");
By JobManagementandMonitoringlink = By.linkText("Job Management and Monitoring");
By RunJobbutton = By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_GridViewJobs_ctl09_btnRun");
WebElement RunJobBut;

//Constructor
public SFQA_Administrator(WebDriver driver)
{
    this.driver1=driver;
}

public void Startup()
{
    driver1.manage().window().maximize();

}

public void LogintoAdministrator(String Uname, String Pass)
{
    driver1.findElement(SysopUserName).sendKeys(Uname);
    driver1.findElement(SysopPassword).sendKeys(Pass);
    driver1.findElement(AdminLoginButton).click();
}


public void JobListPage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    driver1.findElement(JobManagementandMonitoringlink).click();
    Assert.assertTrue(driver1.getPageSource().contains("Job list"));
}

public void runjob()
{
    if(driver1.findElement(RunJobbutton).isDisplayed())
    {
        RunJobBut.click();
    Assert.assertFalse(driver1.findElement(RunJobbutton).isDisplayed(), "The Run Job Button is Hidden in IF Loop");
    }
    else
    {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(RunJobbutton));
        RunJobBut.click();
        Assert.assertFalse(driver1.findElement(RunJobbutton).isDisplayed(), "The Run Job Button is Hidden in Else Loop");
    }               
  }
}
```

Below is my Test Case code:

```
package com.SF.TestCases;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.SF.Pages.SFQA_Administrator;

public class Administrator_Test_Case{

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
SFQA_Administrator logon = new SFQA_Administrator(driver);
By RunJobbutton = By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_GridViewJobs_ctl09_btnRun");

@Test
public void AdministratorLogin() {
    logon.Startup();
    driver.get("url");
    logon.LogintoAdministrator("user","password");
    String Title = "Welcome to Admin site";
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains(Title));  
}

@Test
public void JobListPageValidation()
{
logon.JobListPage();
}

@Test
public void checkRunbutton()
{
logon.runjob();
  }
}
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Does @Test initialize the private fields in that class? That might be the issue because I'm seeing a NullPointerException in there... try to figure out on which variable.

Comment: You declared variable `WebElement RunJobBut;` but not initialized it. Maybe it is a reason?

Comment: The NullPointer is on the driver variable within the WebDriverWait. This is because upon initialization of the object it is creating the WebDriverWait prior to instantiating the driver (Well, assigning the instantiated driver to the driver1 variable). The wait needs to be instantiated in the constructor in order to correct this.

Comment: Why flagged as off-topic? Deals with a QA issue, extremely specific but similar to questions asked all of the time. There were requests for more information but if you look at the stacktrace and code there is all of the information you need. Should not be closed.

Comment: @PaulMuir that sounds like an answer as opposed to a comment ;)

Comment: @PaulMuir Because NullPointerException is not a problem specific to QA. It's basic programming question.

Comment: I flagged it again to close it off-topic. The question is dead, but gets a lot of visitors. java.lang.NullPointerException is a programming issue even when used with a QA framework. Please read this to debug the NullPointerException: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871825/a-good-way-to-debug-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 1):

Your driver is null when you're creating the WebDriverWait.

```
WebDriver driver1;
//At this point, driver is not initialized.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver1,20);
By SysopUserName = By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_Login1_UserName");
By SysopPassword = By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_Login1_Password");
By AdminLoginButton = By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_Login1_ButtonSubmit");
By JobManagementandMonitoringlink = By.linkText("Job Management and Monitoring");
By RunJobbutton = By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_GridViewJobs_ctl09_btnRun");
WebElement RunJobBut;

//Constructor
public SFQA_Administrator(WebDriver driver)
{
    this.driver1=driver;
}
```

Use this:

```
WebDriver driver1;
WebDriverWait wait;
By SysopUserName = By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_Login1_UserName");
By SysopPassword = By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_Login1_Password");
By AdminLoginButton = By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_Login1_ButtonSubmit");
By JobManagementandMonitoringlink = By.linkText("Job Management and Monitoring");
By RunJobbutton = By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_GridViewJobs_ctl09_btnRun");
WebElement RunJobBut;

//Constructor
public SFQA_Administrator(WebDriver driver)
{
    this.driver1=driver;
    this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver1,20);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SQA.

Instead of me investigating what happens in this particular case, I think it will be more helpful for this and similar questions to understand how to

- [read stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)
- [see an actual value of your variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239150/looking-for-an-easier-way-to-write-debugging-print-statements-in-java) (i.e., debug with `System.out.println()`).
- read from JavaDoc for Java API, what each exception means, e.g., [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

That will be useful to you not only in this particular case but also in your further adventure with test automation and generally programming.

Another option is to pair with a programmer in your company or your city and learn from him or her. My experience is that watching how someone else  investigates a problem is much better way to learn things than explaining that here. This is a classical example of tacit knowledge.

Comment: If it's more helpful, but not an answer to the question, then this should be a comment. Stack Exchange avoids boilerplate answers. Boilerplate comments, those are a little more okay.